# cvUpdateMotionHistory in Python/OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I want to use the function cv.UpdateMotionHistory in my python/opencv application.Using the new python interface:

```
UpdateMotionHistory(silhouette,mhi,timestamp,duration)-> None
```

Here how to the parameter timestamp? in C, I can simply use built-in function **clock()**. In python, I try to use **time.time()**, but it fails. I try to use the opencv function **cv.GetTickCount()**, it fails either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import time
CLOCKS_PER_SEC = 1.0
seconds = time.clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC
```

Comment: you mean put the variable **seconds** at the timestamp position? it does not work.

Comment: @PinkyJie, strangely enough, I have everything working. By the way they do exactly the same in `OpenCV2.2\samples\python\motempl.py`

Comment: @PinkyJie, may be posting a small piece of your code could help me to figure out what's going wrong

Comment: with the help of motempl.py, i finally correct my code. There is nothing wrong with "timestamp", the real reason is my buffer is not correctly allocated. Thanks!